# Spreading religion with caravans

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

I'm a bit confused as to how I should interpret religious pressure from caravans.

[image]

As I understand, establishing this trade route will net Venice 1 Gold and 4 Science while I recive 6 Gold. But what of the 12 pressure? It's pointing towards my city. Does this mean that I'm preassuring Venice or beeing pressured? Venice is a Holy City in this game if that matters in any way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pressure is towards your city.

Normally religion pressure is only exerted to a certain range around any particular city.  Venice being a religion-founding holy city doesn't change that range.  Trade routes bypass this range limit mechanic, and the cities will be considered in range once connected by a trade route.  So presumably by this, Venice is out of range to pressure you normally, but setting up a caravan will allow their religion to spread your way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure if Venice were close enough, the religious pressure from proximity would stack with that from the trade route.

Comment: @DavidHarkness - nope, it actually doesn't stack.  You can't double dip pressure from a single city, just stack up already converted cities.  Easiest way to see this is later in the game setting up trade routes between your own cities, at least some of which should be inside the radius.

Comment: When both are present, which wins: proximity, trade route, or the larger of the two?

Comment: @DavidHarkness - Making some assumptions based on this answer, the in-game documentation, and and my own question from the game I'm currently in, it doesn't matter. Pressure seems to be based purely on the city exerting it, not distance. So a given city is either exerting pressure on another (through proximity, trade, or both) or not. There is no concept of one way being better than the other.   That said, I have no idea how the pressure value itself is calculated. Relative size?

Comment: The *amount* of pressure is based on the game speed, from very low for a marathon game to very high for a quick game.  Some civs get bonuses to pressure; e.g. Arabia causes double the normal religious pressure when spreading religion through a trade route.  Choosing Religious Texts will increase the amount of pressure exerted by cities of that religion by 25% (50% after Printing Press is researched).  More details here: [Religious Pressure](http://www.carlsguides.com/strategy/civilization5/religion/convertingandreligiouspressure.php)